# Move term to a different vocabulary

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms

I want to move a term from one vocabulary to another.  In drupal 7 one can use [taxonomy manager](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_manager) to do this but drupal 8 branch has not implemented MOVE yet and the module has not received any update in some time.

Taxonomy merge that is suggested in [this thread](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/220664/how-to-move-a-taxonomy-term-from-one-vocabulary-to-another) has not even been ported in drupal 8 yet.

Thus the only way that is left to do such a task is programmatically.

How do you update programmatically the vocabulary or a term?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should load existing term using term id and then update vid of term from new vocabulary vid then save it.

```
use Drupal\taxonomy\Entity\Term;

$term = Term::load($tid);
$term->vid->setValue('ID value');
$term->Save();
```

Answer (score 0):

https://www.drupal.org/project/term_manager

You can use Term Manager to move Term to new Vocabulary